# How to draw a semicircle inside of another one in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I am having trouble drawing a partial circle inside another circle.

The outer shape is actually a lower case "b" with a font converted to outlines, so as you can see, the circle is not perfectly round.

You can see the general idea I'm going for - I want that semicircle inside to be equidistant from all parts of the inside of the "b". If you look very closely, it's not. I just drew a circle and stretched it.

How can I do this properly?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few steps to this, but it's pretty simple:

- Start with your original letter shape and convert to paths
- Use `Object > Compound Path > Release` to separate the paths that make up the letter
- Select the inner shape and use `Object > Path > Offset Path` to create an inner circle
- Select the new inner path and use `Object > Path > Offset Path` again
- Select both inner paths and go to `Object > Compound Path > Make`
- Create a suitable shape and use Pathfinder to chop away the part of the newly created shape that you don't want or delete unwanted points
- Use `Object > Compound Path > Make` to recombine the original character paths

The below illustration shows the steps:
[image]

Hope that's clear.

Comment: This was amazing and with it I was able to do exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!